# Propagation of electric fields in circuits: lack of conceptual understanding

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

I have trouble understanding some fundamental properties about electricity and have the following conceputal questions:

Say that we have a small battery (for example 1 V) and an very long wire made of a hypothetical material with zero resistance and connect it to one of the ends and wrap it around the earth and connect it to the other end:

- Would there still be current in the wire? Certainly the electric field from the battery end would be undetected at such long distances as it is proportional to 1/r^2?
- My understanding is that the electrons close to the battery end will start moving and cause a "chain reaction" in the wire and generate an electric field that propagates through the wire. Then my follow up question would be why currents travel so fast even though the drift velocity of electrons is extremely slow? What understanding am I lacking here?

Comment: :) Have a look at these Veritasium videos: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY) & [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI_X2cMHNe0)

Answer (score 1):

If the wire has no resistance, there is no electric field along it. Both ends connected to the battery have the same potential.

Inside the battery, there is an electrochemical reaction, with positive ions moving from the negative to the positive pole. The reaction is completed when electrons move through the wire from the negative to the positive pole. Otherwise it is soon stopped due to the electric field inside.

Comment: "If the wire has no resistance, there is no electric field along it."   V=IR Is a steady state solution of the drude model of conductivity under the assumption there is zero acceleration of the electrons, In the absence of a resistive force the zero acceleration state solution is reached when there is no potential difference across the wires.  Does this mean that there is no potential difference across any wire with zero resistance?  No, of course not. This is only true given we assume a constant current. In no way would a  battery and a zero resistance wire give rise to a constant current.

Comment: Applying $\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} $ for the situation you describe would violate the electrostatic condition

Comment: @jensenpaull remember that the battery has internal resistance. So, it is possible a steady state with a wire with zero resistance. The wire plays the role of a bridge for the electrons. The driving force is the internal electrochemical reaction.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual model of this kind of system, energy is transmitted by the electromagnetic field outside the wire. The wire guides a radial [TEM mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode) outside the wire at the speed of light (modified by surrounding material). The electrons need only move a short distance to perform this guidance function.